# Custom property on RealityKit Entity EXC_BAD_ACCESS in unit test

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, entity, realitykit

I have a super basic Custom Entity in like this.

```
class BasicEntity: Entity, HasModel {
    
    var someProperty: Int?
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.green, isMetallic: false)
        let modelComponent = ModelComponent(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        self.model = modelComponent
    }
}
```

I try and unit test it like this.

```
func testPropertyAccess() {
    let basicEntity = BasicEntity()
    basicEntity.someProperty = 1
    XCTAssertNotNil(basicEntity.someProperty)
    XCTAssertEqual(basicEntity.someProperty, 1)
}
```

But I always get an crash like this.

```bash
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
```

Here are some supporting screen shots.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing and doing wrong?

Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400) running unit test against the iOS Simulator iPhone 8

Answer (score 0):

If I refactor like this my test succeeds.

```swift
class BasicEntity: Entity, HasModel, HasSomeProperty {
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.5)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.green, isMetallic: false)
        let modelComponent = ModelComponent(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        self.model = modelComponent
    }
}


struct SomePropertyComponent: Component, Codable {
    var someProperty: Int?
}


protocol HasSomeProperty where Self: Entity {
    
}

extension HasSomeProperty {
    var somePropertyComponent: SomePropertyComponent {
        get { components[SomePropertyComponent.self] ?? SomePropertyComponent(someProperty: nil) }
        set { components[SomePropertyComponent.self] = newValue }
    }
    var someProperty: Int? {
        get { return somePropertyComponent.someProperty }
        set { self.somePropertyComponent.someProperty = newValue }
    }
}
```